# USB Midi device name problems under Windows

Tags: usb, midi

I have been working on a small synthesizer for tesla coils, and have some issues with the USB Midi implementation. I need to support multiple devices connected to the same PC, with each one having a nickname, that can be given to it with a configuration software. I can successfully change the port names from the firmware, but as soon as I connect more than one, windows decides that they should all have the same names.

For example:
stick 1 is called "foo";
stick 2 is called "bar";
-> when plugging in only stick 1 or stick 2 the midi ports have the correct names, but when connecting both, they are both shown as "foo" or "bar".

The weird thing is, that when the midi software is open with only one plugged in, and I attach a second one, they are both listed with the correct names, until I restart the program.

The devices all have an individual USB serial number, and USBDevview as well as the windows device manager shows them as having the correct names, but in any midi software the ports have the naming issue described above. Is this a problem with my implementation, or because of the windows midi subsytem getting confused?

I am not trying to find a OS level workaround for this, but rather to make it work out of the box.

EDIT: I just realised that in windows Midi ports and devices aren't necessarily the same thing, if this is so, from what source does windows get the names for the Midi ports?

Comment: Have you tried other MIDI software to see if it's a bug in the software you're using?  My go-to for this sort of thing is MIDI-OX, but it doesn't like hotplugging devices so you need to restart it each time to see the new ports.  There are some issues with MIDI devices on Windows when they are named the same thing, in that they become ambiguous, but I've never noticed the problem you're describing.  I'm wondering if the software you're using is trying to get around the Windows MIDI device name ambiguity by inspecting the VID/PID or some other descriptor.

Comment: I have tried this with Anvil studio, FL Studio, midi-ox, synthfont and VMPK (this has a known issue with midi ports that have the same name), they all have that naming problem. 
I have also tried to change the PID on one of the devices (which is obviously not an acceptable solution :P) and then it works, and the ports have different names.

Comment: What is the configuration software doing, specifically?  I bet it's just writing out a new INF file with the new name and installing the driver.  In that case, what's probably happening is that two INF files are matching the same VID/PID, and only one gets used.  It's weird that you see the correct names in Device Manager, but maybe those come from the descriptor then.  This is getting out of my knowledge territory... I'm just guessing, based on some messing around I've done with other MIDI devices and their INF files in the past.

Comment: The configuration software writes a nickname to each individual device (which can be changed). At the moment, those devices respond to the USB request for the interface and product string descriptor, with that nickname. It is not ideal, as it requires a reconnection to update the name in the os, but that would be acceptable. I have also tried to completely uninstall the devices with USBDevView, incase some naming was still cached, but that didn't change anything.

Which INF files exactly are you referencing? Maybe checking out the names in them can tell me more about the origin of the issues